# Frequency of non-zero or specific number in a column

Tags: r, matrix, frequency

My input file:

```
 x <- read.table(textConnection('
      t0  t1  t2  t3  t4
  aa  0   1   0   1   0
  bb  1   0   1   0   1
  cc  0   0   0   0   0
  dd  1   1   1   0   1
  ee  1   1   1   0   0
  ff  0   0   1   0   1
  gg  -1  -1  -1  -1  0
  hh  -1  1   -1  1   -1
 '), header=TRUE)
```

I want to firstly calculate the frequency of each columns, i.e.

```
          t0   t1   t2   t3   t4
freqency  5/8  5/8  6/8  3/8  4/8
```

And then multiply the frequency back to matrix x, to obtain the new matrix as follows:

```
       t0    t1     t2     t3     t4
  aa   0     5/8    0      3/8    0
  bb   5/8   0      6/8    0      4/8
  cc   0     0      0      0      0
  dd   5/8   5/8    6/8    0      4/8
  ee   5/8   5/8    6/8    0      0
  ff   0     0      6/8    0      4/8
  gg  -5/8  -5/8   -6/8   -3/8    0
  hh  -5/8   5/8   -6/8    3/8   -4/8
```

How to do it with R? I learnt from manuals that prop.table(x) could be used to get the overall probability for the whole table, how can I do it for each column individually?  Pls kindly help.

Comment: @Catherine : To be correct, you're not working with a matrix but with a dataframe. That difference is quite important in R, so be sure you understand the differences between the types.

Comment: @Catherine : Second, if you're the same Catherine as the one that got suspended and then called herself sally, be careful. If the admins find out you keep on making new accounts, you can be banned from the site based on IP address. So if you don't agree with the suspension, please write at team@stackoverflow.com and explain your case. If you keep your questions up to this level, the suspension can be lifted for me. But you need to stay within the rules of SO, and making different accounts is strictly forbidden.

Comment: My you have many personalities: http://stackoverflow.com/users/729550/sally. This circus act must stop.

Answer (score 7):

In the same spirit as the answer from @Joris, this is where the wonderful `sweep()` function comes into it's own:

```
> sweep(x, MARGIN = 2, colMeans(abs(x)), "*")
       t0     t1    t2     t3   t4
aa  0.000  0.625  0.00  0.375  0.0
bb  0.625  0.000  0.75  0.000  0.5
cc  0.000  0.000  0.00  0.000  0.0
dd  0.625  0.625  0.75  0.000  0.5
ee  0.625  0.625  0.75  0.000  0.0
ff  0.000  0.000  0.75  0.000  0.5
gg -0.625 -0.625 -0.75 -0.375  0.0
hh -0.625  0.625 -0.75  0.375 -0.5
```

What is happening here is that `colMeans(abs(x))` is a vector of length 5. We `sweep()` these values, column-wise (indicated by the `MARGIN = 2` in the call), over the data `x` applying the function `*` as we go. So, the values in column `t0` all get multiplied by `colMeans(abs(x))[1]`, the values in column `t1` all get multiplied by `colMeans(abs(x))[2]` and so on.

The advantage of `sweep()` is that it is *very* fast when given a matrix:

```
X <- data.matrix(x)
> system.time(replicate(1000, sweep(X, 2, means, "*")))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.115   0.000   0.118 
> system.time(replicate(1000, mapply(`*`, x, means)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.308   0.001   0.309 
> system.time(replicate(1000, mapply(`*`, X, means)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.204   0.000   0.205
```

It is much slower when given a data frame:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000, sweep(x, 2, means, "*")))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.072   0.000   2.074
```

But that is just the way things are in R.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
> colMeans(abs(x))
   t0    t1    t2    t3    t4 
0.625 0.625 0.750 0.375 0.500
```

for the frequencies and

```
> mapply(`*`,x,colMeans(abs(x)))
         t0     t1    t2     t3   t4
[1,]  0.000  0.625  0.00  0.375  0.0
[2,]  0.625  0.000  0.75  0.000  0.5
[3,]  0.000  0.000  0.00  0.000  0.0
[4,]  0.625  0.625  0.75  0.000  0.5
[5,]  0.625  0.625  0.75  0.000  0.0
[6,]  0.000  0.000  0.75  0.000  0.5
[7,] -0.625 -0.625 -0.75 -0.375  0.0
[8,] -0.625  0.625 -0.75  0.375 -0.5
```

to get the dataframe. `mapply` applies the function `*` on every column, taking the arguments mentioned. See also `?mapply`